# In python, how to find a primitive element of finite field?

Tags: python, galois-field, finite-field

Say, I want a finite field containing $2^n$ elements for some positive $n$. How to get a single random primitive element in Python, different from that provided by the Conway polynomial?

I know that Python's Galois library gives the option to calculate "GF.primitive_elements" or "GF.primitive_element" but I need two things:

1. Only one primitive element (not all) for each primitive polynomial (Referring to the method "GF.primitive_elements").
2. A single random primitive element different from that provided by the Conway polynomial (Referring to the method "GF.primitive_element")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To test if an element is a primitive element of GF(2^n), determine the prime factors of (2^n)-1, then calculate all the products of all the combinations of those factors except for all of them. Then to test if the element α is a primitive element of GF(2^n), α^p != 1, for all p of any of the products of combinations of factors (except for p = product of all factors, in which case β^p == 1, for any element β of GF(2^n)).

For GF(2^8), 2^8-1 = 255, factors of 255 are 3, 5, 17, the products of combinations are 3 * 5 = 15, 3 * 17 = 51, 5 * 17 = 85. Then to test if the element α is a primitive element of GF(2^8): α^15 != 1, α^51 != 1, α^85 != 1. If none of these powers == 1, then α is a primitive element.

For GF(2^16), 2^16-1 = 65535, factors are 3, 5, 17, 257, products are 3 * 5 * 17 = 255, 3 * 5 * 257 = 3855, 3 * 17 * 257 = 13107, 5 * 17 * 257 = 21845, so 4 tests would be used.

Comment: *"any of the products of combinations of factors"* in your example includes 3, 5, 17 and 1, so shall those be tested or not?

Comment: @KellyBundy - both 3 and 5 are tested when testing α^15 != 1, both 3 and 17 are tested when testing α^51 != 1, and both 5 and 17 are tested when testing α^85 != 1. Note that larger values of n can involve the product of  3 or more terms, not just 2 terms as in the case of GF(2^8).

Comment: @KellyBundy - to clarify, what this is checking for is a cyclic sub-group. If α is a primitive element of GF(2^n), then α raised to the powers {0, 1, 2, ..., n-2} = 1, α, ..., α^-1, will equal every non-zero number of GF(2^n). If α is not a primitive element, then powers of α will cycle back to 1 before reaching α^(n-1). By checking for α^15 != 1, then it will be known that it didn't cycle at 3, 5, or 15 elements. (If it cycled at 3 elements, it would cycle 5 times for α^15).

Comment: @KellyBundy - for example GF(2^4) with primitive polynomial x^4+x^3+1 (hex 19). In the case of trying α = hex a, then you get a^0 = 1, a^1 = a, , a^2 =  b, a^3 = 1, resulting in a cyclic subgroup of size 3. For α = 3, 3^{0 1 2 3 4 5} = 1 3 5 f 8 1, subgroup size = 5. For α = 2, 2^{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f} = 1 2 4 8 9 b f 7 e 5 a d 3 6 c 1, producing all 15 non-zero elements before cycling back to 1.  For any GF(2^n) there are totient((2^n)-1) primitive elements. For GF(2^4), totient(15) = 8 elements. for GF(2^6), totient(63) = 36, for GF(2^8), totient(255) = 128.